# Unable to resolve memory read and segmentation fault error in C++

Tags: c++

I am coding a solution program for leetcode. I have encountered memory read errors and segmentation fault errors which I am unable to resolve. I have tried tinkering with the code to try and remove the errors.
For example: in the `numIslands` function's last lines, I had tried declaring `coordinates` as an array rather than a pointer but the results did not change.
`*(last + 1) = *(coordinates + 1);` does not seem to work at all in the `numIslands` function. I am totally blank about what to do next.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

namespace p200 {
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::endl;
    using std::string;
    using std::vector;
    using std::map;
}

class Solution {
private:
    int count_islands = 0;
    
public:
    int *last;
    int numIslands(vector<vector<char>>& grid) {
        if (grid.size() == 0) return count_islands;
        if (grid.size() == 1 && grid[0].size() == 1) return grid[0][0] - 48;
        vector<vector<int>> grid_copy;
        vector<int> in;
        for (size_t index = 0; index < grid.size(); ++index) {
            for (size_t index0 = 0; index0 < grid[index].size(); ++index0) {
                (grid[index][index0] == '0')
                    ? in.push_back(0)
                    : in.push_back(INT_MAX);
            }
            grid_copy.push_back(in);
            in.clear();
        }
        int * coordinates = new int[2];
        *coordinates = 0;
        *(coordinates + 1) = 0;
        last = new int[2];
        *last = *coordinates;
        *(last + 1) = *(coordinates + 1);
        find_island(grid_copy, coordinates);
        return count_islands;
    }

    void find_island(vector<vector<int>> & arg_grid, int* arg_coordinates) {
        if (arg_grid[*arg_coordinates][*(arg_coordinates + 1)] == INT_MAX) {
            *last = *arg_coordinates;
            *(last + 1) = *(arg_coordinates + 1);
            map_island(arg_grid, arg_coordinates, 1);
        } else {
            if (*(arg_coordinates + 1) < arg_grid[*arg_coordinates].size()) {
                *(arg_coordinates + 1) = *(arg_coordinates + 1) + 1;
                find_island(arg_grid, arg_coordinates);
            }
            if (*(arg_coordinates + 1) == arg_grid[*arg_coordinates].size()) {
                if (*arg_coordinates == arg_grid.size()) return;
                *arg_coordinates = *arg_coordinates + 1;
                *(arg_coordinates + 1) = 0;
                find_island(arg_grid, arg_coordinates);
            }
        }   
    }

    void map_island(vector<vector<int>> & arg_grid, int* arg_coordinates, int arg_new) {
        arg_grid[*arg_coordinates][*(arg_coordinates + 1)] = count_islands + (arg_new * 1);
        if (arg_new) count_islands = count_islands + 1;
        if (*arg_coordinates != 0 && *arg_coordinates - 1 == INT_MAX) {
            *arg_coordinates = *arg_coordinates - 1;
            map_island(arg_grid, arg_coordinates, 0);
            *arg_coordinates = *arg_coordinates + 1;
        }
        if ((*arg_coordinates < arg_grid.size() - 1)
             && *arg_coordinates + 1 == INT_MAX) {
            *arg_coordinates = *arg_coordinates + 1;
            map_island(arg_grid, arg_coordinates, 0);
            *arg_coordinates = *arg_coordinates - 1;
        }
        if (*(arg_coordinates + 1) != 0 && *(arg_coordinates + 1) - 1 == INT_MAX) {
            *(arg_coordinates + 1) = *(arg_coordinates + 1) - 1;
            map_island(arg_grid, arg_coordinates, 0);
            *(arg_coordinates + 1) = *(arg_coordinates + 1) + 1;
        }
        if (*(arg_coordinates + 1) < arg_grid[*arg_coordinates].size() - 1
            && *(arg_coordinates + 1) + 1 == INT_MAX) {
            *(arg_coordinates + 1) = *(arg_coordinates + 1) + 1;
            map_island(arg_grid, arg_coordinates, 0);
            *(arg_coordinates + 1) = *(arg_coordinates + 1) - 1;
        }
        find_island(arg_grid, last);
    }
};


int main() {
    vector<vector<char>> input;
    input.push_back(vector<char>({'1','1','1','1','0'}));
    input.push_back(vector<char>({'1','1','0','1','0'}));
    input.push_back(vector<char>({'1','1','0','0','0'}));
    input.push_back(vector<char>({'0','0','0','0','0'}));
    Solution solver;
    cout << "Number of Island: " << solver.numIslands(input) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply write `last[1] = coordinates[1];` instead of `*(last + 1) = *(coordinates + 1);`?

Comment: never knew that syntax works, lemme try it. EDIT: syntax works but does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: You are learning C++ from the wrong source.

Comment: @Vishwad, Have you tried to run your code in a debugger ? It may show you better info such as the lines of code where your app crashes and the current values of some key variables at the time of the crash.

Comment: Run the program in the debugger that came with your development tools. Wait for program to crash. Inspect the call stack to see if it provides any useful information. Use the information to help narrow down the search.

Comment: Use `vector.at()` instead of `operator[]`. It supports bounds checking and will produce more readable error message than `Segmentation fault. Core dumped`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have ran it through gdb. After a bit of digging, the error is this:

```cpp
    void find_island(vector<vector<int>> & arg_grid, int* arg_coordinates) {
        if (arg_grid[*arg_coordinates][*(arg_coordinates + 1)] == INT_MAX) {
            *last = *arg_coordinates;
            *(last + 1) = *(arg_coordinates + 1);
            map_island(arg_grid, arg_coordinates, 1);
        } else {
            if (*(arg_coordinates + 1) < arg_grid[*arg_coordinates].size()) {
                *(arg_coordinates + 1) = *(arg_coordinates + 1) + 1;
                find_island(arg_grid, arg_coordinates);
            }
            if (*(arg_coordinates + 1) == arg_grid[*arg_coordinates].size()) {
                if (*arg_coordinates == arg_grid.size()) return;
                *arg_coordinates = *arg_coordinates + 1;
                *(arg_coordinates + 1) = 0;
                find_island(arg_grid, arg_coordinates);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the second `if`, you do a bounds check and then increment. You should first increment then to the bounds check, like this:

```cpp
*arg_coordinates = *arg_coordinates + 1;
if (*arg_coordinates == arg_grid.size()) return;
```

Also please use`vector.at()` instead of `operator[]`. It produces more readable and easier to interpret debug messages. Also as other people pointed it out `*(arg_coordinates + 1) = arg_coordinates[1]`, which would make for a more readable code.

For other similar issues I recommend a debugger.

Edit: I ran the code and realised that there is some other bug within it. One of the islands is counted twice, so it gives the wrong result, but that is not technically the issue at hand.